# HTML5 Geolocation not working, 404 in some browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation

I have a web app that uses geolocation. It works on most browsers in most locations which is great. However sometimes I get a 404 error. I have attached it in the image below.

The javascript call to the geolocation function is done like this...

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, geo_error, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 600000, timeout: 600000 });
```

Does anyone know why in some cases I get this 404? Is it due to the network conditions that this specfic machine is on?

[image: Error message]

Thank you

Comment: Which browser are you using? And are you using Ethernet or Wifi?

Comment: Chrome is the browser in question and its on Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid I don't have an immediate solution. A quick search in Chrome forum showing that this issue appeared recently. You might need to wait for an upgrade of google browser.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116986

Answer (score 1):

Working with geolocation and GPS enabled applications, you should assume that for some cases, the geolocation *is* going to fail and you should build an exception handling component that does not fail if errors do occur with geolocation. Your application should continue functioning even if the current GPS location was not correctly fetched due to an error or a user denying permission for the browser to provide the GPS location.

Comment: Yes I agree it needs to degrade gracefully but it would still be good to know why this error happens.